# No implementation for List<? extends Vehicle> annotated with @Named(value="vehicles") was bound

Tags: kotlin, guice

I want to inject a specific list of implementation classes to my `Service` class in a specific order via guice. I cannot use `@ProvidesIntoSet` because that will inject all implementations of my interface and I don't want that. I want to inject only some implementations and they should be in order. So, in my Module, I have this

```
    @Provides
    @Named(value = "vehicles")
    fun getVehicles(
        car: Car,
        bus: Bus,
    ): List<Vehicle> {
        return listOf(
            car,
            bus
        )
    }
```

Now, when I try to inject this list in my Service class like

```
class VehicleService @Inject constructor(
     @Named("vehicles") private val vehicles: List<Vehicle>,
...
```

I get an error like

```
     No implementation for List<? extends Vehicle> annotated with @Named(value="vehicles") was bound
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are running into this issue (https://github.com/google/guice/issues/1282.) with implied wildcard types.

You need to add @JvmSuppressWildcards as described in https://github.com/google/guice/issues/1641.